# Class Path and maven profile

Tags: maven, classpath, maven-profiles

I have 3 jars namely jar1,jar2,jar3.

In jar1 there is some code which reads the file from the classpath. However the file won't be present in classpath of jar1. Instead, jar2 will be plugged in as dependency of jar1 and jar2 classpath would contain that file.

I have jar3 which will also contain the same file in its classpath but I would declare the scope as `test` for jar3 in `pom.xml` of jar1.

Now when the test cases are executed how can we tell maven to always take the file from jar3 (scope as test) classpath although jar2 is given as main dependency (scope not as test)?

Is this possible through maven profiles? If yes how can we specify it?
Or can we use maven-resources-plugin to copy the file during test scope?

How exactly does classpath will be set if the same files are present in multiple jars given as dependency?

Sample jar1 pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>jar2</artifactId>
            <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>jar3</artifactId>
            <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Both jar2 and jar3 has the resource file.

**Question**: Which will be picked up and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dependencies are at the same level in the dependency tree, the order of declaration in your pom will win, as per [Maven Dependency Mediation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) doc:

> Note that if two dependency versions are at the same depth in the dependency tree, until Maven 2.0.8 it was not defined which one would win, but since Maven 2.0.9 it's the order in the declaration that counts: the first declaration wins

So in your case the two dependencies are at the same level in the dependency tree (first level, declared in the POM) and `compile` scope would be present whenever `test` scope would be, as such `jar2` would win because you declared it first in your POM (according to the snipped you posted).

If you want the file to be loaded always from `jar3` but only during tests, simply declare `jar3` first in your dependencies. It will not impact the final deliverable (being in `test` scope) but it will define the order to the classpath for testing and as such giving you the expected scenario. You don't need Maven profiles for that.

---

A simple test case to verify it:

Let's define a property `file.properties` into `src\main\resources` of a Maven project. The file would look like the following for project `resource-provider` (artifactId):

```
property=from-resource-provider
```

And as following for project `resource-provider2` (artifactId):

```
property=from-resource-provider2
```

Note: the same file name into two different projects with different content.

Then in a consumer project (`resource-consumer`) we could have the following sample JUnit test case:

```
public class MainTest {

    @Test
    public void checkClassPath() {
        InputStream is = MainTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/file.properties");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(is);
        System.out.println(s.nextLine());
    }

}
```

For the following dependencies into `resource-consumer`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
        <artifactId>resource-provider2</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
        <artifactId>resource-provider</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Output of test execution would be:

```
-------------------------------------------------------  
 T E S T S  
-------------------------------------------------------  
Running com.sample.MainTest   
property=from-resource-provider2  
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.051 sec
```

So, the first dependency declared, `resource-provider2`, won (note the scope, `test`).

Changing the dependencies order to:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
        <artifactId>resource-provider</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
        <artifactId>resource-provider2</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Would instead give the following output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------   
 T E S T S   
-------------------------------------------------------   
Running com.sample.MainTest   
property=from-resource-provider   
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.07 sec
```

Note: this time `resource-provider` won, because it was declared first and because `compile` scope is also part of `test` scope, while the contrary is not true.

Comment: @svsteja you're welcome. Side note: when using such approach (based on ordering) I would recommend to add comments to your pom to help maintenance and troubleshooting to other developers or to the future yourself :)